# Date Format in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I need to convert this value using expressions in reporting services
From 20100804 to  Day 04 , Month 08, Year 2010

Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but how to do it will depend on whether `20100804` is a string, a number or a date (which you have formatted Scandinavian-style).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this expression.

```
= Format(DateTime.ParseExact("20100804", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "'Day 'dd' , Month 'MM', Year 'yyyy")
```